# UPSERT from Cloud Page to Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

Is there a way to do an upsert from a CloudPage to a Salesforce Sales Cloud Object? In this case the need is to update the Account Object.

Scenario: A new subscriber is created in marketing cloud and receives an email (double opt in)

if he/she activates the email with a standard button I can change the data extension in marketing cloud but I also need to update the CRM. How do I do an upsert from here? is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` function, to update a field on a specific record in Sales Cloud, as per below:

```
%%[
var @result, @accountid
set @accountid = RequestParameter("AccountID")
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Account',@accountid,'DoubleOptIn','TRUE')
]%%
```

If you need a solution which can either update or create a record, you will need to use a combination of three functions:

1. [CreateSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm)
2. [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm)
3. [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm)

Which should be combined as follows:

```
%%[
var @rowset, @numberOfRows, @i, @update, @create, @lastname
set @lastname = RequestParameter("lastname")
set @rowset = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'FirstName, Email', 'LastName', '=', @lastname)
if not empty(@rowset) then
set @numberOfRows = RowCount(@rowset)
for @i = 1 to @numberOfRows do
set @update = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',Field(@row, "Id"),'DoubleOptIn','TRUE')
next @i
ELSE
  set @create = CreateSalesforceObject(
        "Contact", 4,
        "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
        "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
        "DoubleOptIn", 'TRUE',
        "Email", RequestParameter("email")
       )
ENDIDF
]%%
```

Comment: Hey Lukas, thanks for your answer. Does this function also create a new record in case it is not present in the Sales Cloud Object?

Comment: @Yattaman - I have updated my answer accordingly. You will need some more code to achieve that